# Are there any Debuggers present for glsl?

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, glsl

I am unable to print any statements in glsl files. Is there any debugger for glsl files? As in I spotted something called glslDevil, but I find only broken links for that. Are there any other debuggers for glsl ?

Regards,
G

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which OS you're using. On MacOS, you have [OpenGL Shader Builder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGLShaderBuilderUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). It's not exactly a debugger, but you can enter glsl programs into it and it will show you errors and display the output if it's a valid program. There are probably similar apps for other OSes.

In general you can't step through a glsl program or add print statements because the program is executing on multiple (usually hundreds) of fragments at the same time. Also, it's on the GPU, so printing isn't practical.

One technique I've used is it modify the program to produce debug output as colors. For example, when dealing with normals, have the x, y, and z put into the red, green, and blue channels so I can check that they're pointing where I expect.

If you explain what you're trying to debug, we may be able to give additional advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think glslDevil was available on this site: http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/glsldevil/
Both downloads, for windows and linux work great for me.